# What is best way to fix this loose bumper?

Tags: repair, bumper

Under the passenger side headlight of my car you can see the front bumper is hanging loose as a result of hitting humps.

I've seen youtube videos of people just gluing it back or using strings.

Is the glue method effective or not or is it something that comes loose again?

What would you recommend for a cheap, quick yet effective diy repair.

My main concern is I dont want the bumper to fall off when driving.[image]

Comment: It largely depends on what has broken, and how the bumper was held on originally - any chance of getting a photo of the fixings behind the bumper in that area? What is the make and model of the car?

Comment: I guess its a Hundai Cupé (or Tiburon, as they call it in asia)

Comment: You may find the act of simply removing and refitting the bumper allows you to re-engage all of the lose clips with no need for any new parts.

Comment: That's a bumper COVER. Some clips and tie straps from Amazon,

Answer (score 2):

Plastic Cable Ties/Zip-Ties are cheap and durable. If the bumper cover is damaged so proper mounting can't be accomplished, I'd use Zip-Ties for a cheap but semi-permenant fix.

Use any manner of twist drill bit (HSS, Cobalt, etc) to make hole(s) in the plastic bumper to accommodate the Zip-Ties, loop them around what's available.

Obviously the best repair would be to replace the bumper cover and attach it properly. You could call around to some junkyards and see if they have one in your color.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Zip-ties for a quick cheap fix but AZ has the self help isle and they have the plastic v bolts like would have came on the bumper that clip to the headlight bracket pertty cheap. Hope this helps!